# How do I regain access if there is no recovery partition?

Tags: factory-reset, locked-out

I have an android tablet which has no recovery partition, as I have been told in the place where I bought it.

When I hold the buttons for the recovery mode, the image of the robot with the front open up shows, but no menu is shown. There are no vol+ nor vol- buttons but I attached an USB keyboard and hit arrow-up and arrow-down keys with no success. The keyboard is correctly detected, I have use it with this tablet.

I forgot the password and cannot log in. The device is not set in developer mode neither.

Is there any workaround for this or will I have to throw the tablet in the bin?

**UPDATE**

The tablet is a Wolder miTab Air. I am not sure about the Android version but I would say it is Ice Cream Sandwich.

Comment: What make and model of device do you have?  What version of Android were you at?

Comment: @Goblinlord Updated to answer your question. Cheers

Comment: I've just added the `locked-out` tag to your question. As this topic pops up quite frequently here, we've setup some first-aid in [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) which you might wish to check.